# Compiling hping3 on Raspberry Pi. Linker error: cannot find -ltcl

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, libraries

I am trying to install hping on a Raspberry Pi 2. I downloaded the source from GitHub, https://github.com/antirez/hping.

After executing `./configure` I tried `make`, but I got an error message from the linker:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcl

libtcl8.6 is installed, and it is located in `/usr/lib/arm-linux/gnueabihf/libtcl8.6.so` `/usr/lib/arm-linux/gnueabihf/libtcl8.6.so.0`

Can I solve this issue by making a soft link? If so, where? I am not sure where the linker is looking for the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-ltcl` will search for a file named `libtcl.so` in standard library paths whereas yours is named `libtcl8.6.so` in a quite odd location (which may be normal on Raspbian though).

The issue here is that your [hping Git source](https://github.com/antirez/hping/) contains an already-generated `configure` script without its `configure.ac` source (or a hand-written configure script which mimics autotools scripts).

If you look in your `configure` script, [you will see](https://github.com/antirez/hping/blob/3547c7691742c6eaa31f8402e0ccbb81387c1b99/configure#L61) it looks for some optional specific Tcl versions in fixed locations which does not match your system:

```bsh
#
# TCL detection
#
for TCLPATH_TRY in "/usr/bin/" "/usr/local/bin/" "/bin/"
do
    for TCLVER_TRY in "8.4" "8.3" "8.2" "8.1" "8.0"
    do
        #....
```

---

You should edit this configure script to add:

1. your library path
2. your library version

Then, re-run `configure` script, carefully read its outputs (it should print `TCL_LIB: -ltcl8.6`), and try a `make`.

Comment: It was just as you said. Thank you very mucho :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wouldn't use TCL, run `./configure --no-tcl` before attempting to issue `make`.
BTW, before you would do that install `libpcap-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install  libpcap0.8 libpcap0.8-dev libpcap-dev
```

otherwise it will refuse to compile.

Dirty and quick way (didn't tried that, but usually it works) to fix `cannot find -ltcl` it is symlink

```
ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux/gnueabihf/libtcl8.6.so.0 /usr/lib/arm-linux/gnueabihf/libtcl8.6.so
```